# Crystal reports - one subreport overlaps a second subreport beneath it

Tags: crystal-reports, subreport

I'm quite new to CR and I've created a report which has a couple of sub reports in the same group.

The first sub report due to its nature can have one or many lines.  The second sub report which I need to position beneath it is a getting overlapped when SR1 has too many lines.

I'd have expected it to have been pushed down the group by the expansion of the first but this isn't happening.

Bit stuck now but still looking for answers in CR - any help though is gratefully received.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, just found this that if you enter design mode, right click the groups and add a group below the SR1's section, this will remove the overlap.